# Fixing permissions for writing cUrl output to a text file

Tags: php, curl

I am making a web application that grabs one page from the internet using cUrl and updates another page accordingly. I have been doing this by saving the HTML from cUrl and then parsing it on the other page. The issue is: I can't figure out what permissions I should use for the text file. I don't have it saved in my  /public/ html folder, since I don't want any of the website's users to be able to see it.  I only want them to be able to see the way it's parsed on the site.

Here is the cUrl code:

```
$perfidlist = "" ; 

$sourcefile = "../templates/textfilefromsite.txt";
$trackerfile = "../templates/trackerfile.txt";

//CURL REQUEST 1 OF 2
$ch = curl_init("http://www.website.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
<more cUrl options omitted>
ob_start();
$curl2 = curl_exec($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($ch);

//WRITING FILES
$out = fopen($sourcefile, "r");
$oldfiletext = fread($out, filesize($sourcefile));
fclose($out);

$runcode = 1  ;
```

And the part where I save the text file:

```
/*only writing a file if the site has changed*/

if (strcmp($oldfiletext, $curl2) !==0)
{
    $out = fopen($sourcefile, "w");
    fwrite($out, $curl2);
    fclose($out);

    $tracker = fopen($trackerfile, "a+");
    fwrite($tracker, date('Y/m/d H:i:s')."\n");
    fclose($tracker);

    $runcode = 1 ; 
}
```

I am receiving an error at that last '$out = fopen($sourcefile, "w");' part that says:

```
Warning: fopen(../templates/textfilefromsite.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/share/nginx/templates/homedir.php on line 72
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Both your file and the folder it's in, must have proper write permissions. Folders usually have 755, while files are 644. You could use 777 for files, but that isn't recommended.

Comment: Did you include the /usr/share/nginx/templates/ folder to nginx? If not, then the web server cannot access to the file

Comment: Skatox, yes it can access it - just can't write to it. Fred, the 755 and 644 codes mean that only the server can write to it, right? Like, some random user couldn't overwrite the text file? And also, some random user couldn't view the text file?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite it if you use the `w` switch, but append to it using the `a` switch.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I tried changing the file permissions but I am still getting the same errors. Do I need to change any permissions within the larger /templates/ folder? I don't want that readable by the public.

Comment: Actually, can someone explain the difference between 'group' and 'owner'? I just changed the permissions for the text files to 664 instead of 644 and it's working, but I'm not sure if that's an OK thing to do privacy-wise?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/ it explains it very well.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up having to change it to 666 because I tried it from another computer and got the same error about it not being able to write.

Comment: Since you solved this, could you please post & accept an answer, to help others who read thsi question in future? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with file/folder permissions. I ended up changing the permissions for the file to '666' meaning '-rw-rw-rw-' and it worked.